# foreach loop in sql scripts?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, csv

In powershell I use `foreach` to run a function through a list of targets.

I was wondering that if there is any thing similar to `foreach` in sql, so I can run the same query through multiple DBs I chose and save the results to one csv file?

Comment: What you are doing can be done in powershell as well. So why use tsql and then dump into a csv file ?

Comment: I was trying to have less parties involved if I could done it from only one source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Kin mentioned, while you can do this in T-SQL, PowerShell is still viable and potentially a lot easier, especially when you leverage [dbatools](https://dbatools.io/).

You can use [`Get-DbaDatabase`](https://docs.dbatools.io/#Get-DbaDatabase) to not only get the databases but also easily filter out problematic ones you probably don't want to execute against (system dbs, offline dbs, etc):

```
Get-DbaDatabase -Status 'Normal' -ExcludeSystem -OnlyAccessible
```

And then run [`Invoke-DbaQuery`](https://docs.dbatools.io/#Invoke-DbaQuery) to run your command against each of the databases returned.

Comment: This is great!  I really need to get on the dbaTools.io train.  Hopefully soon!

Comment: I ends up with `foreah ($db in $dbs ) {invoke-sqlcmd......}`

Answer (score 5):

Absolutely.  We definitely have FOR loops.

https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/loops/for_loop.php

From the site:

```
DECLARE @cnt INT = 0;

WHILE @cnt < cnt_total
BEGIN
   {...statements...}
   SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
END;
```

There is also a "FOREACHDB" functionality and even foreachTable

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1414/run-same-command-on-all-sql-server-databases-without-cursors/

https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic271576-5-1.aspx
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26496864/how-to-loop-through-all-sql-tables

**But quite a few articles on why it (foreachdb) may be unreliable.**

**Here's an Aaron Bertrand version, which is much better:**
https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/issues/448

This is the direct link.
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/